# Regarding @JsonAnyGetter, @JsonAnySetter issue

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, fiddler

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class XYZ {

    @JsonSerialize(using = ISODateSerializer.class)
    private Date startDate;
    @JsonSerialize(using = ISODateSerializer.class)
    private Date endDate;
    private Map<String, Object> other = new HashMap<String, Object>();


    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> any() {
      return other;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String name, Object value) {
      other.put(name, value);
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setJsonMap(Map<String, Object> other) {
      this.other = other;
    }

}
```

Also i have an json output that looks like this:

```
{
  "startDate": "2014-08-23",
  "endDate": "2014-08-24",
  "sumOfOrderValuesSquared": 178,
  "values": [
    {
      "position": 4,
      "value": "your statement closing date in <b>March 2015</b>.",
      "pValue": 0,
      "rawValue": "your statement closing date in <b>March 2015</b>.",
      "calculated": {
        "conversionRateStdErr": 0,
        "visitPercentage": 0.000016899313887856152,
        "conversionRate": 0
      }
    },
     {
      "position": 5,
      "value": "your statement closing date in <b>April 2015</b>.",
      "pValue": 0,
      "rawValue": "ass</b>.",
      "calculated": {
        "conversionRateStdErr": 0,
        "visitPercentage": 0.000012,
        "conversionRate": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now my problem is i need to iterate over "values" object. It is comming out as arraylist but i dont know the type of arraylist and how to iterate it, so i am not able to iterate over it.

Also ,
I am making server to server rest call using httpClient apache api, but it is not getting trap in fiddler.
I am using java appliction on windows 7 machine. Any idea.
Thanks

Comment: You should really design your class better than that for starters. A "one size fits all" `Map` is almost never a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Design a class for each of your values in the array and use an instance variable for a `List` of it:

```
private List<Value> values;
```

Jackson will automatically deserialize. Also, while you are at it, use another instance field for `sumOfValuesSquared`.

Also, you ignore unknown properties but at the moment no property can be ignored since you have a `JsonAnySetter`.

If you really insist on using such a map, however, use an `ObjectNode` instead. At least you'll be able to navigate it using everything that `JsonNode` can do for you. And annotate it with `@JsonUnwrap`.

Comment: ya , i am not suppose to modify the class. I am new to JsonNode, can you explain in little bit detail how to iterate. Thanks